# WPF DataGrid Binding Performance Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, data-binding, datagrid

My datagrid has a number of programmatically added columns.

```
dgData.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Width=50, Header = e.Naam, Binding = new Binding(String.Format("Figures[{0}]", e.Id)) });
```

The collection that is set to the item source of the data grid is an collection of Data items

```
public class Data
{
    private string _set = "";
    public string Set
    {
        get { return _set; }
        set { _set = value; }
    }

    private Dictionary<long, int> _figures;
    public Dictionary<long, int> Figures
    {
        get { return _figures; }
        set { _figures = value; }
    }
}
```

When I set the collection to the itemssource, it takes ages before the datagrid has been populated with data, sometimes (with about 25 columns) up to 30 seconds or more!

My XAML is pretty clean:

```xml
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="dgData">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Set" Binding="{Binding Set}" Width="100"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Are there any tips to improve the performance of this binding? *If I remove the binding, at column creation, it performs okay!*

Comment: Do you add the columns before or after setting the ItemsSource?

Comment: I add them before setting itemssource

Answer (score 4):

Please try setting both `EnableColumnsVirtualization` and `EnableRowVirtualization` properties to true, at least this will improve population performance, though scrolling still will be slow.

Comment: It is a slight performance improvement indeed! Thanks for the tip, but I still need to wait about 15 seconds. Copying of the datagrid with headers takes up to 30 seconds!

Comment: If you need faster copy method you will need to implement it by your own (DataGrid uses bindings resolving for each cell and it is very slow process). Just as quick idea - creating LambdaExpresion in runtime, based on selection, which forms csv string for one row and is compiled to delegate. Then it can be used for iterating over all selected rows and setting appropriate clipboard content